# swift playgrounds while文のネストについて

Tags: swift, アルゴリズム

swift playgroundsで何度目かの学び直しをしています。
画像のとおりにコードを打ちまして、赤い宝石までは順調に行くのですが、宝石のマスで止まってくれず、そのまま素通りしてしまいます。
while文のネストが良くないのでしょうか？
`!isOngem` が解除されたら（宝石のマスに来たら）外枠のwhile文から抜けてcollectGemしてほしいのですが、そのまま真っ直ぐ歩いてしまいます。
教えていただけたら助かります。
よろしくお願いします。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

以下が解決前のコードです。

```
func move() {
    toggleSwitch()
    if isBlocked {
        turnLeft()
    } else if !isBlockedRight{
        turnRight()
    }
}
while !isOnGem {
    while !isOnClosedSwitch {
        moveForward()       
    }
    move()    
}
collectGem()
```

Answer (score 2):

Nekketsuuu様にいただいたアドバイスを参考に、以下の修正で解決できました。
ありがとうございました！

```
func move() {
    moveForward()
    if isOnClosedSwitch {
        toggleSwitch()
    }
    if isBlocked {
        turnLeft()
    }
    if !isBlockedRight {
        turnRight()
    }
}

while !isOnGem {
    move()
}
collectGem()
```

Answer (score 0):

ヒント：`!isOnClosedSwitch` が満たされるまで内側の while ループから抜け出せず、`isOnGem` かどうかはチェックされません。

Comment: nekketsuuu様、ありがとうございます。そうなのですか…外側のwhile !isOngem ループは、内側にとって上位概念のようなもので、!isOngemがfalseになれば（宝石の上に来たら）強制的に内側のループから出されるものかと思っていました。この場合、while文をネストするのは良くなさそうですね。今一度かんがえてみます。ありがとうございます！